# Magento get a list of all attributes assigned to an attribute set

Tags: php, magento

I can get a list of attribute set and their respective Id's from code posted elsewhere on the site.  I now need to get a list of attributes that are assigned to a particular attribute set ie/ code and label.
None of the resources I have found on the web or on this site seem to be able to get this information.

Also if possible (but don't mind if its another question) it would be useful to also get potential values/value ids for mutiselects etc if they exist.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here:
[How to get all active attributes of products in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275826/how-to-get-all-active-attributes-of-products-in-magento)

And you can find more info here: http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/

Also have a look at: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options