# How to get all active attributes of products in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am working in a new "Filter by Product" module in Magento, i have a situation where i should retrieve all attributes and their values. I Googled this and found the below code

```
 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
      ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
      ->load();

      //      ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'color') 

$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());

/* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */

$attr = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true);

foreach ($attr as $att) {
    echo " Label : ".$att['label']." Value : ".$att['value']."";
}
```

but this retrieves only the label and value of last attribute from list of all available attributes.

how to i get all the attributes? what am i doing wrong in this code?

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)->getAttributeCollection();

// Localize attribute label (if you need it)
$attributes->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

// Loop over all attributes
foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
    /* @var $attr Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
    // get the store label value
    $label = $attr->getStoreLabel() ? $attr->getStoreLabel() : $attr->getFrontendLabel();
    echo "Attribute: {$label}\n";

    // If it is an attribute with predefined values
    if ($attr->usesSource()) {

        // Get all option values ans labels
        $options = $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        // Output all option labels and values
        foreach ($options as $option)
        {
            echo "    {$option['label']} (Value {$option['value']})\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Just for clarification of the debug code
        echo "    No select or multiselect attribute\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to load this code in my module.. it shows all the attributes but after some times it ends up in error "You cannot define a correlation name 'al' more than once.."

Comment: therefore, you had called more than once a function specifically parent function of the object but to tell the truth which one I don't know.

Comment: ahh.. i fixed the issue.. i removed the code "$attributes->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());" and it works fine now..

Comment: @Vinai : I would like to fetch only attributes assigned to the default category... what filter should i add for this?

Comment: Use `Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY)` if you want category attributes.

Comment: If you only want attributes for a specific attribute set then add that attribute set id to the `getAttributeCollection()` call, e.g. `getAttributeCollection($product->getAttributeSetId())`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first solution:

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
 foreach($this->products as $product) {
   $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
 }
```

If you are using using the data from outside magento, you can use a class I made:
http://blog.alexparadise.com/magento-dbeav-class/

It's beta but that should work in your case.
Or get the concept of the EAV table... and make your own SQL query.